pandas version 2.1.4 method mad()
I looked in the documentation for version 2.1.4 and didn't find anything about Mean Absolute Deviation, which in previous versions was mad(). Can anyone tell me which method in the current version works like mad()?

This method was deprecated in version 1.5 and removed in version 2.0: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.5/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mad.html

@foglerit Yeah, that's kind of the point. OP seems to be looking for an alternative.

You might be able to find some workarounds here - someone better at data science than me could probably write a more complete answer.

mad() method has been deprecated, however, you can still calculate the MAD manually using simple formula with the mean() method and absolute differences.
Here's the code.
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([2, 3, 5, 7, 11])

# Compute MAD manually
mad = (s - s.mean()).abs().mean()

print(mad)

I hope this will help you a little.
